# Resttemplate 404 Not Found

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

I'm trying to send a post to a rest service this way:

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String url = "http://myadress/rest/student.php";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("TIMESTAMP", time);
    headers.add("BASEKEY", hexIv);
    headers.add("ACCESSKEY",accessKey);
    headers.add("SIGNATURE",signature);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(studentsEncrypted,headers);
    String answer = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
```

Is this error only triggered when the service at the destination was not found ?

Answer (score 2):

No, this exception (org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException) is devoted to all HTTP response codes that represents Client error responses (4xx family). See eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status. So it can be as well authorization error.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems a bit surprising that a 404 throws this exception.  404 is a valid return code for many non error scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting 404 error...
Coz I had implemented concept of `context path` and `service registry` in my application.
And while calling one microservice from another, I was **not adding context path  of another microservice as part of microservice-endpoint.
So adding context path to api endpoint resolved the issue for me.